# How do I improve the accuracy of number of weekdays in a month calculation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to work out how many days in a month there are for each day of the week. I've used this question / answer below as a basis for what I want to achieve and it's working for the most part.

[how can we get the number of sundays on an given month ? ( swift )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807700/how-can-we-get-the-number-of-sundays-on-an-given-month-swift)

Unfortunately it's also calculating the 1st day of the following month, if it's a weekday.

I'm not familiar enough with how the code is calculated to be able to understand whether there is anywhere I can add a -1 or something to the total days of the month.

If anyone could recommend a solution it would be most appreciated.

I've tried changing the "numberOfSundays += 1" to "numberOfSundays += 0" as I thought that might be causing the issue.

```
func getNumberOfDaysInMonth (month : Int, Year : Int, nameOfDay: String) -> Int? {

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = Year
    dateComponents.month = month

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)

    guard let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date!) else { return nil }

    let numDays = range.endIndex

    // New code starts here:

    var numberOfSundays = 0

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    for day in 1...numDays {

        dateComponents.day = day

        guard let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else { return nil }

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let dayOfWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // Get day of week

        if dayOfWeek == nameOfDay { // Check if it's a Monday
            numberOfSundays += 1
        }
    }

    return numberOfSundays
}
```

---

```
getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Monday")

getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Tuesday")

getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Wednesday")

getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Thursday")

getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Friday")
```

Where I call the function "getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 06, Year: 2019, nameOfDay: "Monday")" it returns 5 as the number of days in the month of June 2019, in actual fact there are 4.

Comment: That algorithm is way too complicated. What you actually need is only the number of days in the month and the weekday of the first day. No iteration is needed because everything else is a simple formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: Int , year: Int, nameOfDay: String) -> Int? {

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.year = year
    components.month = month

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    guard let date = calendar.date(from: components),
        let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date) else { return nil }

    return range
        .map { DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: $0) }
        .map { calendar.date(from: $0) }
        .compactMap { date  -> String? in
            guard let date = date else { return nil }
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }
        .filter { $0 == nameOfDay }
        .count
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Short and simple. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to find in the documentation of `Range`, however, the documentation comment for `.endIndex` property is:

> The collection's "past the end" position---that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

Anyway, you should not be using indices the calculate the size.
Correctly, you should use:

```
let numDays = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
```

or simply

```
let numDays = range.count
```

to correctly calculate the number of days.

Comment: I'm curious as well. This looks like the most straightforward approach and gets rid of the ridiculous loop in the original code. The only thing I might suggest is moving the dateformatter out since they're expensive to create and there's no reason to do it on each call, but this looks like a perfectly reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested this and it doesn't work. Still returns an inaccurate number of days for any given month.

Comment: @Rich Show the test data. I have tested that with your data (June 2019) and change to `range.count` works correctly. I could make a mistake in the simplified solution, checking that right now.

Comment: @Sulthan Test was using `month: 05, year: 2019` for Monday through Friday. Results came up as 4,4,4,4,4. They should have been 4,4,5,5,5

Comment: @Rich Works correctly with the change. I have removed the other solution though because it has a bug and I don't have the time to fix it right now.